# PyQt application rcc converted image not found in raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS)

Tags: python, qt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian

I'm developing a cross-platform application that runs both on Windows and Linux(in my case is Raspbian). I have converted all images in single file using `C:\Python37\Scripts\pyside2-rcc.exe tests.qrc -o tests_rc.py`. my `tests.qrc` file structure is something like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="images">
    <file>images/Slider_1m.png</file>
    <file>images/Slider_2m.png</file>
    <file>images/Slider_3m.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

after converting to `tests_rc.py` coded like this in the main script:

```
self.SLIDER.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("SLIDER",u"<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><img src=':/images/images/Slider_1m.png'/></p></body></html>", None))
```

that perfectly loaded in windows app no need to original image files anymore.
But in raspbian, this kind of image wont load and I have to define location like this:

```
self.SLIDER.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("SLIDER",u"<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><img src='/home/pi/Myproject/ui/images/Slider_1m.png'/></p></body></html>", None))
```

As you see I set the exact image location. This is the way I have found to view in raspbian app and my `tests_rc.py` file is totally useless. What should be do to use `tests_rc.py` file in raspbian as same as windows?

Comment: Does other resource files work? Are you completely sure that you're using the same resource file in both OS and that you're correctly importing it?

Comment: I have 3 various resource files like this and all works fine in Windows, over 100 times I checked files and replaced for months, I'm writing my codes in Windows and move to Rasp

Comment: @MohammadFarahi please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have `mainicons.qrc` file contains:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="images">
    <file>images/calibration_.png</file>
    <file>images/media_.png</file>
    <file>images/menu_.png</file>
    <file>images/upgrade_.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

converted to `mainicons_rc.py` file, then imported to this simple example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

import mainicons_rc

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()
   textLabel = QLabel(widget)
   textLabel.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("TestInitWindow", u"<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/calibration_.png\"/></p></body></html>", None))

   widget.setGeometry(50,50,300,300)
   widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Example")
   widget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

The problem was: used to be I convert it to rcc resource file using `C:\Python37\Scripts\pyside2-rcc.exe mainicons.qrc -o mainicons_rc.py`.
changing `pyside-rcc.exe` to `pyrcc5.exe` solved the issue, now converting command should be like: `C:\Python37\Scripts\pyrcc5.exe mainicons.qrc -o mainicons_rc.py`.
I have checked both generate files are completely different.

Comment: Mixing together PyQt and PySide is considered **bad** practice. We could've been more thorough (you actually "told" us, as tags and title specified PyQt, while you wrote that you used pyside's tool) so that's also on us, but be more careful in the future.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I had to add Pyside tag, but before I got the problem, I didn't think it could be different between these two. Used to be I had had the same issue with pysignal in PySide but It was ok in PyQt.

Comment: If you need to provide compatibility with both PyQt *and* PySide I suggest using [Qt.py](https://github.com/mottosso/Qt.py), which allows transparent usage of both modules, **but** this won't allow you direct usage of files generated for resources; I never used it with pyside, so I'm not sure they are completely compatible, but you could *try* to just change the import statement on top of the generated _rc file and see if it works, in that case you can use Qt.py for that too, just by changing the import accordingly (you obviously need to remember to update the file whenever contents change).

Comment: Be also aware that starting from PyQt6, pyrcc has been removed, as the maintainer decided that it wasn't required anymore (some of us disagree with his motivations, but that's it); nonetheless, it seems that pyside is keeping their tool available for the time being.